# Getting a fraction approximation from a list

Tags: python, list, matching

I'm just beginning in Python.

This is for a gear rate calculator.

I have a list of 5000 integers in the range 367 to 7645373  and an original fraction, it could be 1/10 or 34561/43521 to 10/1.

I need to make a new fraction having a value as close to the original fraction, made from a numerator and a denominator that exist in the table.

In fact I want a list of matches sorted by it's deviation from the original fraction.

I have a solution but it takes ages to give a result with values as 1/10, as solutions like 367/3670 or 368/3680 or 4352/43520...are equivalent.

How a Pythonist would do it?

Please don't tell me it's a case for a C library! :D

Cheers 
Antonio

```
def searcharatio(l, a):
    b = []
    mx = l[-1][0]
    ln = l[0][0]
    ld = l[0][0]
    i = max(int(ln/a.numerator-1), int(ld/a.denominator)-1)
    print i
    while 1:
        n = a.numerator * i
        d = a.denominator * i

        if n > mx or d > mx:
            return sorted(b)
        if n > 0.9*ln and d > 0.9*ld:
            # enumerate es lista 2 elem 0=num orden, 1=elemento
            ri = (min(enumerate(l), key=lambda x:abs(x[1][0]-n)))
            ro = (min(enumerate(l), key=lambda x:abs(x[1][0]-d)))
            ln = ri[1][0]
            ld = ro[1][0]

            e = [abs(1.0 - ((float(ln)/ld) / (float(n)/d))), i, ri, ro]
            b.append(e)
        i+=1
```

Comment: so you want to make a list of those `(numerators, denominators)` whose fractions are same from given range/list of values??

Comment: How close to the original fraction? Need to know to narrow down the 25M possible fractions which all will deviate to some degree from it.

Comment: If you sorted your data in to a BST and then walked that from each node, I think it would help you narrow down on your best candidates faster.

Comment: So you're saying this does what you want but is too slow, right?

Comment: What are the contents & format of the `l` argument passed to the function? It's not a simple "list of 5000 integers in the range 367 to 7645373".

Answer (score 2):

Python tends to be slow at iteration; a vectorised solution using NumPy is likely to be faster.

```
def search_ratio(l, a):
    l = np.array(l)
    t = l.astype(float).reshape(-1, 1) / l.reshape(1, -1)
    i = np.unravel_index(np.argsort(np.where(t > a, t / a, a / t).flat), t.shape)
    return l[i[0]], l[i[1]]
```

For example, `search_ratio(range(2, 6), 1.3)` will give:

```
(array([4, 5, 3, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 2, 3, 2, 2]),
 array([3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 5, 4, 2, 3, 5, 4, 5]))
```

as `4/3` is the closest ratio to 1.3, `5/4` is the next closest etc.

Note that `t`, the table of available ratios, can be cached for efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

```
from __future__ import division
import itertools

def searchratio(input_range):
    my_ratios=set()
    for x in itertools.combinations(input_range, 2):
        y=x[0]/x[1]
        if y==1/10 or (10/1>y>34561/43521):
            my_ratios.add(x)
    return my_ratios

if __name__=='__main__':
    from time import time
    t1=time()
    nk=len(searchratio(xrange(4000)))
    t2=time()
    print t2-t1, nk
```

in python; it is taking 6.5 seconds for the list of `4000` items 
in pypy; it is taking 3.25 seconds for the list of `4000` items 
and if you want to decrease it even further; you have to choose `cython` or put your code in parallel processing of `ipython`.
easy step will be just run your code in `pypy-c` (`https://pypy.org/` ); you can immediately see the time reduction of `50%`.

Comment: This will be slower than it needs to be only because you're calling append on a list which is notoriously slow.

Comment: for `your_inputlist`= range(4000) it took 79 sec on my laptop

Comment: I wasn't talking about `your_inputlist`. Calling `append` on `my_final_list` is what I was referencing. Where else do you see a call to the `append` method on an object?

Comment: that's why i wrote my answer what i have just found; 79 sec.
is there any alternative of append to make it fast?

Comment: Ah I thought you meant calling `range(4000)` took 79 seconds (it didn't sound right, but I've heard more bizarre things). A faster way would be a list comprehension, but then you remove the idea of checking the set first. I guess there isn't a better way in this instance.

Comment: @sigmavirus24: now its pretty fast. it took just 12 sec for `your_inputlist`= range(4000) and 11 sec for xrange(4000). see the updates.

Comment: Awesome. Yeah, I never deal with globals so I forget what few nice features they have. :P You might also include the speed in your reply for OP.

Comment: Works great with 4000 values, but i have 40000, and with that many values It triggers page swapping.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate all results and sort afterwards.

```
from collections import namedtuple
import random

fraction_target = 1 / 10.0
limit_left = fraction_target * 0.9
limit_right = fraction_target * 1.1

result = namedtuple('result', 'val1 val2 fraction')

values = [random.randint(367, 7645373) for _ in range(5000)]

fraction_results = []
for value_1 in values:
    for value_2 in values:
        fraction = value_1 / float(value_2)
        if limit_left < fraction < limit_right:
            fraction_results.append(result(value_1, value_2, fraction))

fraction_results.sort(key=lambda x: abs(x.fraction - fraction_target))

print(fraction_results[0:10])
```

I limited the stored results to a level from 90% to 110% of the wanted fraction.

Comment: `fractions` is the name of a standard module.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will be any help, due to the limitations of this solution, but I'm posting it nonetheless since the theory at least is very applicable to your problem.

I'll assume your list is simply a list of numbers. So let's first make it a `set`, since we're repeatedly checking for membership, and that's faster with a set:

```
integers = set(integers)
```

Now, the `fractions.Fractions` class has a nifty method called [`limit_denominator`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction.limit_denominator), which may be of help to you. It is based on [Euclid's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm), which can be used to construct something called a [continued fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fractions) for any real number. The continued fraction of a number may then be used to construct the best rational approximations of that number with a given denominator constraint.

So to apply it to your problem, we start with the `Fraction` you wish to represent and call `limit_denominator` repeatedly with a limit just below the denominator of the previous approximation until we find a fraction whose numerator and denominator are both in `integers`. Since larger denominators mean better approximations, the first match is the best one.

```
import fractions

def best_approximation(numerator, denominator, integers):
    min_int = min(integers)
    max_int = max(integers)
    org_frac = fractions.Fraction(numerator, denominator)
    if org_frac > 1:
        # the numerator is larger than the denominator, so our maximum 
        # denominator must be adjusted down accordingly, since we also
        # want the numerator to be below max_int
        curr_max = int(max_int / org_frac)
    else:
        curr_max = max_int
    while True:
        fr = org_frac.limit_denominator(max_int)
        if fr.numerator < min_int or fr.denominator < min_int:
            return None
        if fr.numerator in integers and fr.denominator in integers:
            return fr
        max_int = fr.denominator - 1
```

I've tested it with a integer list that's just the prime numbers between 367 and 7645373, and I get this output:

```
>>> print best_approximation(34561, 43521, integers)
4513/5683
```

This is still not as fast as it could be, since the internal structures built by the `limit_denominator` methods could have been reused. You could fix that by copying the source code and modify it, or just implement the algorithm from scratch by using the wikipedia articles.

The limitations I mentioned is this: It may happen that no best approximation is found using this method. If the integers list is too sparse, this may be a problem. In the specific case of my prime list and using random numerators and denominators from 7645373 to 17645373 it only works for about half the cases, which is clearly not good enough. On the flip side, when you get an answer you'll know it's a very good approximation.

Answer (score 0):

I ended using bisect with a sorted list.

```
import bisect
import random
import time
def searchratio(t,n,d):
  #n must be <= d if it's not he case swap ,and swap the results returned
  b=[]
  a=float(n)/d
  t0=t[0]
  x1=bisect.bisect(t,t0/a)
  print a,x1,t0
  lm=len(t)-2
  for ti in t[x1:lm]:
      x1=bisect.bisect_left(t,ti*a)
      b.append([t[x1],ti])
      b.append([t[x1+1],ti])
  b.sort(key = lambda x:abs(x[0]/float(x[1])-a))
  return b   

#-----test program--------------------------------------------------   
l=[random.randrange(100000,10000000) for i in xrange(100000)]
l.sort()
n=3
d=100
t=time.clock()
r=searchratio(l,n,d)
t=time.clock() - t
print t, len(r), float(n)/d 
for x in r:
    print x, x[0]/float(x[1])
```